# Problema com execução de comandos

Tags: ruby

Atualmente eu estou fazendo alguns testes com a execução de comandos através do mouse e com loops, veja abaixo:

```
if $MouseOnEvent == -1 
  if @teste == 1
    print "test"
    @teste = 0
  end 
end

if $MouseOnEvent != -1
  @teste = 1
  return
end
```

A condição diz que sempre que o mouse estiver fora de tal área, ele vai executar o comando "print". Quando sair, ele apenas seta para que a condição seja feita novamente.

Meu problema, é que quando a condição é satisfeita, o comando print é executado várias e várias vezes(mais ou menos umas 30), até que ele pare(isso não deveria acontecer já que na primeira vez ele já deveria mudar o valor de @teste), gostaria de saber uma possível causa para isso.

Comment: Tem como você mostrar como é feita a chamada do método em que se encontra esse código?

Comment: Poderia dar mais detalhes do código? Algum contexto, quais bibliotecas estão sendo usadas, etc.